# Ninject Add Binding over the whole assembly / Getting a list of class name in solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am using Ninject to do Dependency Injection. So I would have some code like this

```
ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
ninjectKernel.Bind<Interface1>().To<Class1>();
ninjectKernel.Bind<Interface2>().To<Class2>();
```

and so on. Problem is that I have like 30-50 class in one project and I have 8 projects currently (more to add later). So is there a way to scan over my entire solution and give me a list of interface/classes name? This will enable me to make a for loop like

```
for (...) {ninjectKernel.Bind<Interface[i]>().To<Class[i]>();}
```

Or is there a shortcut way in Ninject?

Comment: Is that really how your interfaces and classes are named? Sequentially?

Comment: I meant having a list of classes in string format perhaps so I can loop through it

Answer (score 1):

I removed my comment because my colleague pointed me to this extension for Ninject:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions

It is convention-based bindings. If you are willing to keep your class/interface names in a convention-format.. then you can make the bindings automatic.